# Re-using the "pre-formatted" text button on sites other than Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

On [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), there is a very useful button for adding code samples:

[image: Stack Overflow]

However, the same button exists on other sites; here is a screenshot from [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com):

[image]

Apart from the tool tip, it's the same. I don't recall seeing that button used on any site except code related sites.

Why not make that button site specific? Eg for [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) it could be used for adding

> spoiler text

On Christianity it could be used for adding a [Bible Gateway](http://www.biblegateway.com/) chapter / verse link. Other sites will have their own ideas.

It's a small help for established users, more of a help for new users who are not familiar with different formatting.

Is this of interest?

Comment: This makes perfect sense, was sure it was already suggested before but couldn't find it.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about hijacking the markdown sequence (e.g. ctrl-K/four spaces) itself, or just replacing the *button* with a different (potentially new) sequence?

Comment: @goldPseudo: I'm not entirely sure what the difference is. But my thought is that the button will look different (different icon) and that the markdown test it generates will be different. I'm not thinking of something beyond that (eg "email me"). Does that answer your question?